# Need opinions about this basic layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I guess this is a simple question... basically it's about layout considerations. So let consider the code below, I get this:

[image: figure A].

```
public class TestCode_Web {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Test");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(200, 300);

    // Inner panel ---------------------------------------------------------

    JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    innerPanel.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 200));
    window.add(innerPanel);

    // Northern panel ------------------------------------------------------

    JPanel panelN = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel labelN = new JLabel("Label");

    panelN.add(labelN, BorderLayout.WEST);
    panelN.setBackground(new Color(200, 250, 250));
    innerPanel.add(panelN, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // Center panel --------------------------------------------------------

    JPanel panelC = new JPanel();
    panelC.setBackground(new Color(250, 200, 250));

    JPanel panelCheckBoxes = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    final JCheckBox c1 = new JCheckBox("C1");
    final JCheckBox c2 = new JCheckBox("C2");
    final JCheckBox c3 = new JCheckBox("C3");
    panelCheckBoxes.add(c1);
    panelCheckBoxes.add(c2);
    panelCheckBoxes.add(c3);

    int width = panelCheckBoxes.getPreferredSize().width;
    int height = panelCheckBoxes.getPreferredSize().height;
    panelCheckBoxes.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    panelC.add(panelCheckBoxes);
    innerPanel.add(panelC, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Southern panel --------------------------------------------------------

    JPanel panelS = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel labelS = new JLabel(String.valueOf(width) + "/" + String.valueOf(height));

    panelS.add(labelS, BorderLayout.WEST);
    panelS.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 200));
    innerPanel.add(panelS, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // ...

    window.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

What I would like is to have this:

[image: figure B]

How could I achieve that ? I guesss there are several ways, I'm waiting for your diverse proposals...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to overwrite the  `getPreferredSize()` method of `panelCheckBoxes` to return `panelC`'s width. This way, `panelCheckBoxes`' size will automatically adapt to the width of `panelC`.

```
final JPanel panelC = new JPanel();
// [...]
JPanel panelCheckBoxes = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1)) {
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(panelC.getWidth(), 
                             super.getPreferredSize().height);
    }
};
```

For accessing `panelC` inside the anonymous inner class, it has to be `final` (i.e., after initialization, the `panelC` variable can not be assigned a new value, which is no problem in your case).

Just setting the `preferredSize` at that point in the constructor will not work, since (1) the size is not known yet, and (2) it might change when the window is resized. You could, however, use `setPreferredSize` *after* the call to `window.setVisible(true);`, when `panelC` got a size:

```
// after window.setVisible(true);
panelCheckBoxes.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(panelC.getWidth(), 
                                               panelCheckBoxes.getHeight()));
```

However, note that this way `panelCheckBoxes` still won't resize when you resize the window.

If you just want the checkboxes to be aligned to the left (but not necessarily stretch over the whole width), a simpler way would be to put `panelC` into the `WEST` container of the `BorderLayout`. Assuming that the colors are only for debugging and in the end everything will be the same color, you won't see a difference.

Finally, for more complex layouts you might want to check out [GridBadLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html). It takes some getting used to, but once mastered, it's worth the effort.

Comment: Hello Tobias, first thank you for your answer! Now I have a couple of questions, I'll start with **question #1:** I tried to replace my declaration of `panelCheckBoxes` with the one you gave, but I have a strange error message: 'cannot refer to a non-final variable panelC inside an inner class defined in a different method'. What (simple thing) can I do to get rid of this?

Comment: Yes, thanx it works pretty well indeed. Now my **question #2** would be what you said about setting `preferredSize` in the constructor.. Could you give me the piece of code for that? This is more a theoretical question as I don't exactly see the point between specifying the `getPreferredSize` and `setPreferredSize()` so maye you can help me to have a better understanding of this point...

Comment: OK, I have a better understanding, but using `setPreferredSize()` still doesn't work well, I guess there's some _refresh()_ method call that's missing... Also it's pretty disturbing to actually use `getPreferredSize` rather than `setPreferredSize` to actually **set** the width of the component.